# Chisel 3: RegInit doubly imported?

Tags: chisel

After upgrading Chisel 3 to git master (a6798ad) I'm getting errors about `RegInit` being imported by both `chisel3.util._` and `chisel3._`. For instance, this happens when compiling chisel-testers (9389343):

```
chisel-testers/src/main/scala/chisel3/iotesters/SteppedHWIOTester.scala:177: reference to RegInit is ambiguous;
[error] it is imported twice in the same scope by
[error] import chisel3.util._
[error] and import chisel3._
[error]     val done           = RegInit(false.B)
[error]                          ^
```

How should this be fixed?

Judging by its log, this commit of chisel-testers was tested against a recent commit of Chisel 3, so I don't even understand how this issue only seems to manifest for me.

Comment: Have you tried using a more recent version of https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers?

Comment: There is only one commit in chisel-testers more recent than the one I was using, and the commit message & contents are unrelated to this issue. Eventually I just went back to using "chisel3" -> "3.0-SNAPSHOT",  "chisel-iotesters" -> "1.1-SNAPSHOT".